# Loop through xml File and create a Textview for every String

Tags: android-studio

I'm new to Android Coding.

I been searching now for a while.

I have a xml File with several Strings.
What I would like to create a Loop which creates a TextView for each String in the .xml File.

Is it possible to have a loop which runs for each string in the xml File?

The Strings do not have any ongoing naming like "String_1" "String_2" and the number of Strings in the xml file can vary.

Thank's for your help

Edit:

Maybe this makes it a bit more clear

I have a LinearLayout (contained by a ScrollView) which should contain several routines with a Description and a Start Button (see the picture).

The idea was to save the Description in a .xml file in order to make translation and the adding of new routines easier.

Therefore, it is not known how many routines will be in the xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="txt_sevenThree1">This Routine is for 10 sets of 7/3 Repeaters with a 3 Minute rest between sets</string>
    <string name="txt_sdag">abc</string>
    <string name="txt_2345">ghj</string>
    <string name="txt_89765">vbnbmbv</string>
    
</resources>
```

That's why I would like to loop through all elements in the xml File.

This is the code to create the TextView and the Button which needs to be executed for every item in this xml file.

```
    public class ChooseRoutine extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_routine);

//        Get the layout of the ChooseRoutine
        LinearLayout layoutMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chooseRouLine);

//        Add layout to contain Button and Description
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);

//        Create Margin for the layout and Button/Description
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        layoutParams.setMargins(40, 40, 40, 40);

//        Create and add the Description TextView
        TextView description = new TextView(this);
        description.setText(getString(R.string.txt_sevenThree1));
        layout.addView(description, layoutParams);

//        Create and add the Start Button for the Routine
        Button btn1 = new Button(this);
        btn1.setText(getString(R.string.btn_Start));
        layout.addView(btn1, layoutParams);

//        Add everything to the main layout
        layoutMain.addView(layout, layoutParams);


    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh9Vz.jpg

Hope that makes it more clear

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you mean by strings here actually 
But according to what i understand you can make a list view in your xml and loop all your strings in list view if you just want to display those strings

Comment: i agree with @RahulKhanna, just learn to make listView or recycerlview, you can look for this tutorial https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview